# What is the working of this function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am newbie in php and javascript.
I want to know about the working of this function.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                echo ('I am in Send Push Nottification');
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Q) My question is how this fuction sending the data php file
Like`(http://uitdevelopers.site40.net/ClientServer/?name=qasim)`
**EDIT**
Here is send_message.php

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

   include_once 'gcm.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

This is my php file and i want to execute it but i cannot understand this function

**Edit**
This is my index.html. Where  i want to call this function 
But it cannot working.
It is working staticaly but when I send data dynamically can't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                echo ('I am in Send Push Nottification');
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
       require_once('db_functions.php');
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="devices">
                <?php
                if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" 
                            onsubmit="return sendPushNotification( $row["id"])">
                                <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="send_container">                                
                                    <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message"
                                     placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send"
                                     onclick="sendPushNotification( $row["id"])"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?> 
                    <li>
                        No Users Registered Yet!
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to know how [jQuery's `$.ajax()` works too](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: it sends data through ajax. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: remove all the necessary code like the styling.

Comment: why are you loading jquery twice?

Comment: It gathers the data from your form in client side by using `$('selector').serialize();`  of jquery and get's all the data inside your php then if your server side has no errors it throws back to your client side to show all data's by using `success` if it is success or `error` if it fails. Ajax is for querying your result without reloading your page.

Comment: Please answer your comment @aldrin27

Comment: do you know how to use your browser's console? you should console the parameters in this line: `error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {` by doing `console.log(errorThrown)`

Comment: @CodeGodie thanks for your comment I am searching how to console then i check this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gathers the data from your form in client side by using `$('selector').serialize();`  of jquery and get's all the data inside your php then if your server side has no errors it throws back to your client side to show all data's by using `success` if it is success or `error` if it fails. Ajax is for querying your result without reloading your page.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` means, call method [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from the object `$`

this method will use http [GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) method, this means that array `data` will be appended to URL `send_message.php` after question mark `?`

as soon as url does not start with `/` or protocol (like http://), current protocol, hostname and path will be used, so final string will be `PROTOCOL://HOST[:PORT]/PATH/send_message.php?form_field_name=form_field_value&form_field_name2=form_field_value2`

after forming full URL, this method will use browser-dependent method (for example [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)) to call this url and call your JS function `success` with result

Comment: Well explanation I add some details can you check why it is not working